# Why is my custom css for wordpress does not work?

Tags: php, wordpress

i am trying to do custom theme in Wordpress and i have problem with my function.php.

My code in it looks like this.

```
 <?php function custom_scripts() {
 wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-main-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
 }
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','custom_scripts');
 ?>
```

Problem is that css does not work. I have style.css in theme directory, not in folder.

Thanks for everything.

Comment: Does it get loaded (network wise) in the final page/html?

Comment: Have you tried `wp_enqueue_style( 'my-theme', get_stylesheet_uri() );` directly?

Comment: @ITgoldman - Hello, if you mean network in devtools so no, it does not get load.

Comment: @saulopaiva - Yes i did and nothing changed :(